# Storing multiple test reports using Allure

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, jenkins-plugins, allure

I run my tests with Jenkins and I use Allure Framework for test report generation. I need to save and switch between different test reports for different launches on Jenkins, is there any way/plugin for doing this?

Comment: Could you please specify a bit more information about your problem? Jenkins plugin saves reports http://i.stack.imgur.com/9OqNM.png

Comment: That's solves my problem :)

Comment: Actually it's not quite clear from the question, what system you're talking about. For example, if you run your tests on your local PC - then you can just rename folders and you're good. Now we already know that you're talking about Jenkins, but you should've made that clear in the original post. I suggest you to rename the question title since I can only propes a change to the post body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Allure+Plugin) for Allure;